# How to combine the contents of 2 Windows directory like Windows Desktop

Tags: windows, desktop

For example, Desktop of Windows (XP, Vista, 7) merged contents of 2 folder (All Users\Desktop and Current User\Desktop)

How to create a folder like this? That display the contains of both 2 different folders?

I'm using Windows XP SP3

Comment: If you paste the content in All users\Desktop, it will be shown on everyone's desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That's functionality of the shell (Windows Explorer) for certain special folder, such as the start menu and the Desktop. It was never meant (and is not) a general tool for merging multiple folders into one view.

As heavyd noted, that's what Windows 7's Libraries are for. They are designed for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7 you can use the **[libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx)** feature to do exactly this.